# i am trying to get selector value, store it in a variable array and pass this array to a success action in account.effect.ts file using ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-selectors

account.effect.ts File

```
fetchUserInfo$ = createEffecct(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AccountActions._fetchAccountInfo),
    switchMap(({accountNumber}) =>
      this.accServvice.getAccInfo(accountNum).pipe(
        map((accountInfo: AccType) =>
          AccountActions.loadUserInfoSuccess({data: accountInfo}),
        ),
        catchError((error) =>
          of(AccountActions.userDataFails({error}))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

In the above file i have imported selector and you can access it by
this.store.select(FromAcc.getSelectedAccInfo). i want to access selector value FromAcc.getSelectedAccInfo and add one more value which i will receive from service and then send it to action AccountActions.loadUserInfoSuccess.
I am very new to ngrx. Please tell me how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below solution

```
fetchUserInfo$ = createEffecct(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AccountActions._fetchAccountInfo),
    // below 2 lines updated
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(FromAcc.getSelectedAccInfo)), 
    switchMap(([accountNumber, selectedAccInfo]) =>
      this.accServvice.getAccInfo(accountNum).pipe(
        map(([accountInfo: AccType, ) =>
          AccountActions.loadUserInfoSuccess({data: accountInfo}),
        ),
        catchError((error) =>
          of(AccountActions.userDataFails({error}))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```